# Oracle external tables - Specifying dynamic filename

Tags: database, oracle, logging, plsql, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE LOG_FILES (
        LOG_DTM VARCHAR(18),
    LOG_TXT VARCHAR(300)
   )
 ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL(
   TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
   DEFAULT DIRECTORY LOG_DIR
   ACCESS PARAMETERS(
      RECORDS  DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
      FIELDS(
        LOG_DTM position(1:18),
        LOG_TXT position(19:300)
      )
   )
   LOCATION('logadm'))
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
/
```

LOG_DIR is an oracle directory that points to `/u/logs/`

The problem though is that the contents of `/u/logs/` looks like this

```
logadm_12012012.log
logadm_13012012.log
logadm_14012012.log
logadm_15012012.log
```

Is there any way i can specify the location of the file dynamically? i.e. every time i run `Select * from LOG_FILES` it should use the log file of the day. (e.g. log_adm_DDMMYYYYY).

I know i can use `alter table log_files location ('logadm_15012012.log')` but i would like not to have to issue the alter command.

Any other possibilities?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a shame you're running 10g.  On 11g we can associate a pre-processor script - a shell script - with an external table.  In your case you could run a script which would figure out the latest file and then issue a copy command.  Something like:

```
 cp logadm_15012012.log logadm
```

Adrian Billington has blogged about [this feature here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513).  Frankly his write-up is more helpful than [the official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#sthref1299).

But as you're on 10g all you can do is run the ALTER TABLE statement, or use a scheduled job (`cron` or whatever) to sync a new file with the generic name.

Comment: Thanks i have updated one of the stored procedures (which uses the table) to update the filename as it also runs every day.